# How to display specified number of data through link parameter?

Tags: javascript, json, json-server

I want to display from json server for example 5 of 100 objects. Is there any parameter like this one which sort?

```
const url = "http://localhost:8000/players?_sort=points&_order=desc";



const url = "http://localhost:8000/players?_sort=points&_order=desc";
    let template = "";

    fetch(url)
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((data) => {
            data.forEach((player, idx) => {
                template += `
            <div class='modal-leaderboard__player-name'>
            <h2>${idx + 1}.&nbsp;</h2>
            <h2 data-player-rank>${player.name}&nbsp;</h2>
            <h2 style='margin-left: auto'>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span data-points-rank>${player.points}</span>&nbsp;points</h2>
            </div>
        `;
            });

            this.rank.innerHTML += template;
        });
```

Comment: needs more detail. which code is running backend? is it well known cms? etc.

Comment: I just want to show 5 results not all db

Comment: there is no way to me know your backend server code. so this must be solved on your backend code. There is now way to solve your problem to just add a key to your url. 

If you share something about your backend system then maybe someone can suggest a solution.

Comment: but all my backend is data from json server

Answer (score 0):

if you mean fo example the first 5 items, can add a condition on var idx :

```
...
 if(parseInt(idx)<6){
     template+=...
     ....
     this.rank.innerHTML += template;
  }
...
```